# How to make bug report command in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

So i couldn't find any code online or anywhere and I'm not personally sure how to make bug report command.
I would want the command work like so it post the report in a dedicated channel.

So it would work like when u send "s!bug-report (bug)" it sends the (bug) to a channel that is in my server.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code snippets so we can see that you actually tried something instead of waiting for someone to spoonfeed you? Also please add more details

Comment: I haven't tried anything cuz i have no idea how to send the messages from any servers to specific channel that is in my own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above comments you mentioned you were stuck because you didn't know how to send messages to a specific channel, so I'll get you started on that.

You can get a `channel` instance by using `Client.get_channel` ([docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel)). This can be called from anywhere so it doesn't matter that it's a channel in your own server, or that it gets called in another server.

```py
# ... command, and whatever else you want to do

channel = client.get_channel(id_of_your_specific_channel_goes_here)
await channel.send(message_you_want_to_send)
```

I'm not, however, gonna give you the entire code just like that. It shouldn't be too difficult to figure the rest out, given that it's just a basic command.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I don't need the whole code that's just what I was looking for!